# What is the sigma-algebra $\sigma(X_t|t\ge 0)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, notation, brownian-motion

In [these notes](https://wt.iam.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/WT/Inhalt/people/Andreas_Eberle/IntroStoAn1516/IntroStochAnalysis2015.pdf) (pg25) a sigma-algebra on $C[0,\infty)$ is introduced as follows:
$$\sigma(X_t|t\ge 0) \quad\text{where}\quad X_t(x)=x_t$$
From what I have learned about the notation I would guess that this sigma algebra is actually:
$$\sigma(\{x|X_t(x)\in A_t\forall t\ge 0\;\text{where}\; A_t\in\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R}^d)\}) $$
firstly is this correct? Secondly to check that the Brownian motion $B$ is measurable w.r.t. this sigma algebra the sets:
$$\{x|X_{t_i}(x)\in A_{t_i}\; i=0,1,..,n \;\text{where}\; A_t\in\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R}^d)\}$$
why is this allows?

Answer (score 0):

For each constituent set, take only finitely many $X_t$.  In fact, since you are taking the generated sigma-algebra, you can take just one $t$.  So
we want the sigma-algebra generated by the sets
$$
K_{t,A} :=\{X_t \in A\} = \{\omega \in \Omega\;:\;X_t(\omega) \in A\}
$$
where we have one set for each $t \ge 0$ and Borel set $A$.  Here $\Omega$ is the sample space, it is not clear what your $x$ is...